# How to implement basic auth in Django

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django, authentication

I want to implement a basic auth dialog style authentication in Django
Example -
When you visit some website, a dialog pops up. It's a native dialog. It has a simple message asking for username, password and below it there are two textboxes to enter username password.

I have searched a bit but did not find anything. Basically, it should look like this - 
[image]
(This pic is from a Rails tutorial. Rails has it in built)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do that.

If you want standard HTTP Basic Auth with static username/password that can be configured via `settings.py`, you can create a middleware. Check http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2468/. It's also quite simple with [Apache](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PasswordBasicAuth) or [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule) so you don't even need Django.

If you want to use your user database to log user in, you can use some decorators. Check: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/243/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/nopped/django-http-auth which gives you the ability to add HTTP Basic Authentication using middleware or decorator on specific views.

Answer (score -1):

You don't seem to have searched very hard, given that a search for "apache authentication" on the Django docs site brings up [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/apache-auth/) which explains exactly and in detail how to do it.